# Concat 2 columns in pandas - AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate along 2 columns in pandas. The code :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels import api as sm
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2015,2,12)
end = datetime.datetime.today()
df = web.get_data_yahoo(['F', '^GSPC'], start, end)

df1 = df.concat(columns=[F['Close'], gspc['Close']], axis=1)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'
```

Comment: What had you done to try to solve this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to use `pd.concat([df1, df2])`, because `df.concat()` doesn't exist.

I'll make you an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(zip(list('bcdfg'), list('aeiou')), columns=['consonants', 'vowels'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(range(5), columns=['numbers'])
```

```
  consonants vowels
0          b      a
1          c      e
2          d      i
3          f      o
4          g      u
```

```
   numbers
0        0
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
```

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

```
  consonants vowels  numbers
0          b      a        0
1          c      e        1
2          d      i        2
3          f      o        3
4          g      u        4
```

Comment: I don't think I can explain it better than the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), but in essence, you need two `pd.DataFrame()` to concatenate. Like this: `df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])`

Answer (score 2):

As Nicolas mentioned, `concat` is a top-level function and doesn't have an equivalent `pd.DataFrame` method. Other than checking the documentation, you can check if there's a `concat` method by:

```py
import pandas as pd
hasattr(pd.DataFrame, 'concat')   # False
hasattr(pd, 'concat')             # True
```

The following are the list of top-level functions that don't have an equivalent `pd.DataFrame` method:

```py
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
{n for n,_ in getmembers(pd, isfunction)} - set(dir(pd.DataFrame)) - set(dir(pd.Series))
```

- `bdate_range`, `date_range`, `interval_range`, `period_range`, `timedelta_range`
- `concat`
- `crosstab`
- `cut`, `qcut`
- `get_dummies`
- `infer_freq`
- `json_normalize`
- `lreshape`
- `merge_asof`, `merge_ordered`
- `read_clipboard`, `read_csv`, `read_excel`, `read_feather`, `read_fwf`, `read_gbq`, `read_hdf`, `read_html`, `read_json`, `read_orc`, `read_parquet`,
  `read_pickle`, `read_sas`, `read_spss`, `read_sql`, `read_sql_query`,
  `read_sql_table`, `read_stata`, `read_table`, `read_xml`
- `set_eng_float_format`
- `show_versions`
- `test`
- `to_datetime`, `to_numeric`, `to_timedelta`
- `wide_to_long`